# do i need a deterministic game engine for ball physics multiplayer game?

Tags: unity, networking

I want to create a simple soccer game but where the ball physics is accurately rendered across the network. I looked at Photon's Quantum engine and it is too expensive for indie devs at 1k/month for only 500 CCU.

Is there an alternative approach? Basically I need the ball physics to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: This sounds like something you can adequately resolve with replication, rather than determinism. Determinism alone isn't a perfect solution, because you always have to handle differing views of history between the two networked devices. Even if they can come to identical conclusions given identical inputs, their inputs will be non-identical and need some form of synchronization fix-up to converge back on a single consensus future.

Comment: @DMGregory hmmm I am confused about what determinism is. So a ball bouncing around between walls, players over network can be fine with replication, but a complex simulation like explosions require determinism???

Comment: Determinism means that, given the same input, all players' games will produce the same output. Like if you remove a key block from a JENGA tower on all player's machines, every player should see the tower collapse the same way, as long as they don't interfere with it. The problem is that in soccer, folks are interfering with the ball a *lot* of the time. So you need the server to tell you "player 2 kicked the ball 20 ms ago" to be able to draw on your screen the result of the kick. So it might as well say "...and now the ball is doing this" rather than count on your sim being exactly the same.